# awk separate rows based on $2 and $17 and do average on $17

Tags: awk

We have an input here:

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

We would like to separate this input.csv into 2 files

If the $2 is the same and the max minus min in $17 <= 1 ", average $17 and put it into "file a".

If the $2 is the same and the max minus min in $17 > 1 ", average $17 and put it into "file b".

Note: If there is an unique $2 itself, we would like to keep it here (cpd-6666666 as an example)

Note: cpd-1111 ($17 max-min) = -1-(-1.3)=0.3 < 1

a: where ($17 max-min)<=1 .  The new $17 in cpd-1111($2) is the average of (-1,-1.1,-1.2,-1.3) = -1.15

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.15,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

b:where ($17 max-min)>1 .  The new $17 in cpd-7788990($2) is the average of (-1,-2,-3) = -2

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

Here is the attempt which could separate input into a and b but haven't done average yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","; f1="a"; f2="b"}

FNR==1 { print $0 > f1; print $0 > f2; next }

$2!=last_id && FNR > 2 { handleBlock() }

{ a[++cnt]=$0; m[cnt]=$17; last_id=$2 }

END { handleBlock() }

function handleBlock() {

if( m[1]-m[cnt]<=1 ) fname = f1

else fname = f2

for( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { print a[i] > fname }  

cnt=0
}
```

May I know if there is anyway to do the average in a and b?  Thanks.

Comment: See also: (1) [Linux: sort $2 & $17 in numerical values; sort distant columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765721/) and (2) [`awk`: separate rows if "$2 are the same and max and min value <= 1" ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747469/) and (3) [Categorize CSV files based on $18 info ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731871/).  I'm not claiming any direct duplicate status; they questions are somewhat related, though (by the data set, if nothing else).

Comment: You say _If the $2 is the same and the max minus min in $17 <= 1 ", average $17 and put it into "file a"._  If `$2` is the same as what? $3?  $2 on the next line?  $2 on the previous line?  Some other condition?  Max what?  Min what?  When a line is the only one with the given value in $2, where should it be printed?  Standard output?  The question needs some serious clarification.  My next comment will attempt to interpret your requirements.

Comment: The data in the input file should be written to three outputs, 'file a', 'file b' and standard output. The output lines should be the same shape as the input records. The heading line (line 1) should be written to all three outputs.  Records should be grouped based on the value in $2.  Data is ordered such that lines with the same value in $2 are adjacent in the input. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ When there is just one record in the group, the line should be written to standard output. Otherwise, the value in $17 should be averaged.  If the average is greater than 1, write the line with the average in place of $17 (of the last line of the group) to 'file b'; otherwise, write to 'file a'.  The other data for the output line should come from the last record read for the group.  There are 21 fields in each row of the input data.

Comment: Couldn't you have described your problem using smaller, simpler input in terms of say fields 2 and 4 out of 5 instead of fields 2 and 17 out of god knows how many? More of us might have looked at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the averages in the output files by altering `handleBlock()` as follows:

```
function handleBlock() {
  if( m[1]-m[cnt]<=1 ) fname = f1
  else fname = f2
    # compute the sum of the $17 fields for the group
  for( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { sum+=m[i] }
    # compute the average
  avg = cnt > 0 ? sum/cnt : sum
    # use the max line for the output, split into an output array: oarr
  fcnt = split( a[1], oarr )
    # modify the 17th field of the output array
  oarr[17]=avg
    # write the updated array to the desired file one field at a time
  for( i=1;i<=fcnt;i++ ) {
    printf( "%s%s", oarr[i], i==fcnt ? "\n" : FS ) > fname
  }
  cnt=0; sum=0
}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753316/1259917) for comments on the original script.